# What is the the Cartesian equation of the plane having x-, y-, and z-intercepts of 2, 5, and 3 respectively?

Tags: calculus, vectors

What is the the Cartesian equation of the plane having x-, y-, and z-intercepts of 2, 5, and 3 respectively?
Im not sure how to do this

Comment: Write the general equation $ax + by + cz = 1$ and substitute $(2, 0, 0)$ for $(x, y, z)$.

Comment: The general equation is $ax+by+cz=k$. What values can you choose for $a$, $b$ and $c$ so that you get the same result for $(x,y,z)$ equal to $(2,0,0)$, $(0,5,0)$ and $(0,0,3)$?

Answer (score 1):

Should be known by heart: if the $x$, $y$ and $z$_intercepts are $a,\ b,\ c$ ($\neq 0$) respectively, an equation is
$$\frac xa+\frac yb+\frac zc=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the equation of the plane can be written as

$$
a(x - x_0) + b(y - y_0) + c(z - z_0) = 0,
$$

where $\vec n = (a, b, c)$ is a normal vector, and $\vec v_0 = (x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is a point on the plane. So to write an equation of a plane, a stand method is to find a point on the plane and find its normal vector.

Here we have $3$ points on the plane, namely $(2, 0, 0), (0, 5, 0), (0, 0, 3)$. To find a normal vector, usually we use cross product of two vectors in the plane.

$$
\vec{n} = (2, -5, 0) \times (2, 0, -3) = (15, 6, 10).
$$

Then the equation of the plane is:

$$
15(x - 2) + 6y + 10z = 0.
$$